# How to fix: Clicking 'Quick Edit' link in Admin (edit.php) makes posts disappear?

Tags: admin, ajax, quick-edit

When I'm logged in and go to the Posts management page (edit.php), **if I click the 'Quick Edit' button, the clicked post disappears from the listing!**

This occurs in FF7 and Safari 5.1, running WP 3.2.1.

Refreshing the page displays the post in the list again, but I can't find a way to use the Quick Edit functionality.

Edit: 
In Post management, after clicking quick-edit, Firebug displays:
`a("input[name=\"ping_status\"]", d).prop is not a function` in `/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-post.js?ver=20110609`

I've tried:

- Clearing the cache in FF, restarting FF, hard refreshing several times (inspired by [a post by Andrew Ozz](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/25-visual-editortinymce-problems?replies=97) re fixing post edit functionality
- Reinstalling WP from the Dashboard > Upgrade menu (repeat the cache clearing / refreshing)
- Deactivated the most relevant / recent plugins (meaning those that edit the admin area, non essential plugins).  I still have a bunch active, but they are crucial - eg Custom Post Type plugins without which the site would break.

Unfortunately, I can't say when this started happening, only that it only happens on this site.

Possibly related issues:

- Clicking the 'Publish immediately' button in the Edit Post page does nothing
- Edit Post: Add a tag / Display most used tags fails
- Yoast SEO: not displayed in tabs, doesn't load the SEO title preview, etc (have switched off the plugin: doesn't resolve the other issues)
- Clicking the 'Edit image' popup button loads the semi-opaque overlay, but no thickbox
- I can no longer upload a new image, though I managed that only half an hour ago :( Upload button does nothing
- Firebug reports: `g.prop is not a function`, in file `wp-admin/js/post.js?ver=20110524`

It seems that the jquery / ajaxy business in admin is failing (seeing lots of `.prop is not a function`).  I previously had an issue with adding links in post content, which is why I mentioned the earlier post.  Clearing the cache / refreshing worked for this issue.

I'm stumped!  Any suggests as to how to proceed would be appreciated,

Regards, Tim

Update: these links are loaded requested twice, but the top ones never resolve ??
[image: Each file is loaded twice, but the top one doesn't resolve]

Comment: looks like your server is not responding on js script requests and that's why none of the ajax functionality works for you.

Comment: Thanks.. funny thing is, the same file is loaded twice: the second one loads fine, the first never resolves..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. that had me stumped for a while!

I had replaced WP's jquery v1.6.1 with a Google-CDN jquery v1.4.2 in my functions.php.

```
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"), false, '');
```

Learnt a few things along the way.. thanks, Tim